# Creating a new list using a stream

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have a StudentSchedule class that contains schedules of a student, the student may switch between rooms over time.  There's no overlap with the date ranges so if a student stops at 2020-01-01 the next record would be 2020-01-02.

Given the StudentSchedule, I want a ProgramEnrollment which disregards room changes and coalesces contiguous StudentSchedules.

So given the following StudentSchedules

```
      new StudentSchedule("A", "1", parse("2020-01-01"), parse("2020-01-02")),
      new StudentSchedule("B", "1", parse("2020-01-06"), parse("2020-01-10")),
      new StudentSchedule("B", "2", parse("2020-01-11"), null),
      new StudentSchedule("A", "2", parse("2020-01-03"), parse("2020-01-04"))
```

I want a result like

```
A 2020-01-01 - 2020-01-04
B 2020-01-06 - null
```

I have extracted the relevant code below.  What I want to do is see if I can change the computeProgramEnrollments() to use more functions or streaming API including groupBy then flatmap then collect to a new list.  Assuming it is possible.

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.time.LocalDate.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(computeProgramEnrollments());
  }

  static Stream<StudentSchedule> schedules() {
    return Stream.of(
      new StudentSchedule("A", "1", parse("2020-01-01"), parse("2020-01-02")),
      new StudentSchedule("B", "1", parse("2020-01-06"), parse("2020-01-10")),
      new StudentSchedule("B", "2", parse("2020-01-11"), null),
      new StudentSchedule("A", "2", parse("2020-01-03"), parse("2020-01-04"))
    );
  }

  public static List<ProgramEnrollment> computeProgramEnrollments() {

        List<ProgramEnrollment> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        String currentProgram = null;
        LocalDate currentStartDate = null;
        LocalDate currentStopDate = null;
        boolean newEnrollmentRequired = false;
        for (final StudentSchedule schedule : schedules().sorted(Comparator.comparing(StudentSchedule::getStartDate)).collect(Collectors.toList())) {
            if (Objects.equals(currentProgram, schedule.getProgram())) {
                if (currentStopDate != null && currentStopDate.plusDays(1).isEqual(schedule.getStartDate())) {
                    // continuation
                    currentStopDate = schedule.getStopDate();
                } else {
                    newEnrollmentRequired = true;
                }
            } else {
                newEnrollmentRequired = true;
            }

            if (newEnrollmentRequired) {

                if (currentProgram != null) {
                    final ProgramEnrollment e = 
                    new ProgramEnrollment(currentProgram,
                    currentStartDate,
                    currentStopDate
                    );
                    ret.add(e);
                }

                currentProgram = schedule.getProgram();
                currentStartDate = schedule.getStartDate();
                currentStopDate = schedule.getStopDate();
                newEnrollmentRequired = false;
            }
        }
        if (currentProgram != null) {
          final ProgramEnrollment e = 
            new ProgramEnrollment(currentProgram,
              currentStartDate,
              currentStopDate
            );
          ret.add(e);
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
class StudentSchedule {
  String program;
  String room;
  LocalDate start;
  LocalDate stop;
  public StudentSchedule(String program, String room, LocalDate start, LocalDate stop) {
    this.program = program;
    this.room = room;
    this.start = start;
    this.stop = stop;
  }
  public String getProgram() { return program; }
  public String getRoom() { return room; }
  public LocalDate getStartDate() { return start; }
  public LocalDate getStopDate() { return stop; }
}

class ProgramEnrollment {
  String program;
  LocalDate start;
  LocalDate stop;
  public ProgramEnrollment(String program, LocalDate start, LocalDate stop) {
   this.program = program;
    this.start = start;
    this.stop = stop;   
  }  
  public String getProgram() { return program; }
  public LocalDate getStartDate() { return start; }
  public LocalDate getStopDate() { return stop; }
  public String toString() {
    return program + " " + start + "-" + stop + "\n";
  }
}
```

https://repl.it/@trajano/StupendousBetterEngines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `collect` since `reduce` is meant for collecting with an immutable result and this is validated to use with *parallel* streams.

```java
return schedules()
  .map(s->ProgramEnrollment.from(s)) // same as @RobAu
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ProgramEnrollment::getStartDate))      
  .collect(
    ArrayList::new,
    (c, e)->{ 
      if (c.isEmpty()) {
        c.add(e);
      } else {
        var top = c.get(c.size() - 1);
        if (!top.getProgram().equals(e.getProgram())) {
          // Program changed
          c.add(e);  
        }
        else if (top.getStopDate() != null &&
          top.getStopDate().plusDays(1).isBefore(e.getStartDate())) {
          // At this point there is a gap with the program
          c.add(e);  
        }
        else if (top.getStopDate() != null && 
          top.getStopDate().plusDays(1).isEqual(e.getStartDate())) {
          // update the stop date with the new stop date
          top.setStopDate(e.getStopDate());
        }
        else {
          throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
      }
    },
    (c1, c2) -> {
      var topC1 = c1.get(c1.size() - 1);
      var botC2 = c2.get(0);

      if (!topC1.getProgram().equals(botC2.getProgram()) ||
          topC1.getStopDate() != null &&
          topC1.getStopDate().plusDays(1).isBefore(botC2.getStartDate())) {
        // Program changed or there is a gap with the program
        c1.addAll(c2);
      } else if (topC1.getStopDate() != null &&
          topC1.getStopDate().plusDays(1).isEqual(botC2.getStartDate())) {
        // update the stop date with the new stop date
        botC2.setStartDate(topC1.getStartDate());
        c1.remove(c1.size() - 1);
        c1.addAll(c2);
      } else {
        // handle cases when the data does not match the preconditions
        throw new IllegalStateException();
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice candidate for group-by/map-reduce!

(we need an additional stream with map to get rid of the optional that is standard in reducing)

### Idea

The idea is to **group** each `StudentSchedule` by program, **map** them to a small `ProgramEnrollment`, then to **reduce** the values of each key by merge or *coalesce* these ProgramEnrollments and finally return a list of the reduced values.

Note that the `reducing` requires at least one entry in the stream to prevent `Optional.empty()`

You could even improve by returning a `Stream<ProgramEnrollment>`.

Note that it is possible to inline the `reductor` and `mapper`, but for clarity I introduced some local values.

### Code

```
public static List<ProgramEnrollment> computeProgramEnrollments() {


    Collector<ProgramEnrollment, ?, Optional<ProgramEnrollment>> reductor = Collectors.reducing(ProgramEnrollment::merge);
    Collector<StudentSchedule, ?, Optional<ProgramEnrollment>> mapper = Collectors.mapping(ProgramEnrollment::from, reductor);

    return
            schedules()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(StudentSchedule::getStartDate))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StudentSchedule::getProgram, mapper))
                    .values()
                    .stream()
                    .map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

### Code - using toMap

`toMap` allows for easier reducing and helps to get rid of the `Optional`.

```
public static List<ProgramEnrollment> computeProgramEnrollments() {

    return schedules()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(StudentSchedule::getStartDate))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(StudentSchedule::getProgram,
                    ProgramEnrollment::from,
                    ProgramEnrollment::merge))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

With some additional methods here (they could also be extracted to a util / converted to static methods on `Main`) :

```
static class ProgramEnrollment {
    ...

    public static ProgramEnrollment from(StudentSchedule s) {
        return new ProgramEnrollment(s.getProgram(), s.getStartDate(), s.getStopDate());
    }

    public ProgramEnrollment merge(ProgramEnrollment e) {
        LocalDate minStart = this.start == null ? e.start : e.start == null ? this.start : e.start.isBefore(this.start) ? e.start : this.start;
        LocalDate maxStop = this.stop == null ? null : e.stop == null ? null : e.stop.isAfter(this.stop) ? e.stop : this.stop;

        return new ProgramEnrollment(this.program, minStart, maxStop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but I think your reducer does not handle the `plusDays(1)`

Comment: It does not seem to handle the gaps

e.g. StudentSchdule(A, 2020-01-01, 2020-01-02), StudentSchdule(A, 2020-01-05, 2020-01-10) should have two resulting entries.

Comment: Oh I see. Good point! I didn't get that straight from the requirements. In that case, the reduce step should be replaced by a merge step that merges all the periods in one go, not too hard because the are sorted. If I find time I will fix it 